# form using action from dropdownlist

Tags: php, forms, select

I have 5 Forms like this

```
<p>
    Form1:
    <form action='Form1.php' method='POST'>
        <input name='charname' id='charname' placeholder='Charname'>
        <input name='server' id='server' placeholder='Server'>
        <input name='region' id='region' placeholder='Region'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit'>        
    </form>
</p>
```

Now I want to replace the 5 forms with a single form, where the `action` is taken from a dropdown-list like this:

```
<select name="dropdown" size="5">
   <option value="form1.php">Form1</option>
   <option value="form2.php">Form2</option>
   <option value="form3.php">Form3</option>
   <option value="form4.php">Form4</option>
   <option value="form5.php">Form5</option>
</select>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use jQuery for this

Example-

**HTML**

```
<select name="dropdown" id="formaction" size="5">
   <option value="form1.php">Form1</option>
   <option value="form2.php">Form2</option>
   <option value="form3.php">Form3</option>
   <option value="form4.php">Form4</option>
   <option value="form5.php">Form5</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
<script>
$("#formaction").on("change", function() {
  var getVal = $(this).val();
        $("#YourFormId").attr("action", getVal); //replace #YourFormId with your form id
});
</script>
```

Comment: change `ver` to `var`

Comment: Thanks, it works! I noticed the mistake with `ver` and `var` and was able to fix it myself. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with javascript,

**Html**:

```
<form action='Form1.php' method='POST' id="form_main">
     <input name='charname' id='charname' placeholder='Charname'>
     <input name='server' id='server' placeholder='Server'>
     <input name='region' id='region' placeholder='Region'>
     <input type='submit' name='submit'>        
</form>

<select name="dropdown" size="5" id="form_test" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex) func();">
   <option value="form1.php">Form1</option>
   <option value="form2.php">Form2</option>
   <option value="form3.php">Form3</option>
   <option value="form4.php">Form4</option>
   <option value="form5.php">Form5</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**:

```
function func(){
   var elem = document.getElementById("form_test");
   var form_val = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
   document.getElementById('form_main').setAttribute("action", form_val);
}
```

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Now, i tried it in my local machine it is working.

Comment: Also tested this and its working, but i prefer the one with jQuery.

Comment: @neverlucky Yeah, you should go with jquery but if you don't use that much javascript there is no reason you to have export jquery library, simple javascript is fine, but jquery is cross browser so you should go with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to use JavaScript to alter the action attribute of the form once the dropdown was changed and prior to the form being submitted. This is a bit hacky though!

Could you not post the data to a single handler then handle the logic in there of what to do with it depending upon the value of the dropdown? It would be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = $( "select[name=dropdown] option:selected" ).val();
```

You can get it by using [.val()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/) function